# Ошибка в discord.ui: AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'

Tags: python, discord

Здраствуйте! У меня такая проблема(ошибка внизу):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View
import random

TOKEN = ''
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.command()
async def roulette(ctx):
    chamber = random.randint(1, 6)
    shoot = random.randint(1, 6)
    if chamber == shoot:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} кринжанул!')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} уцелел! ')

@bot.command()
async def car(ctx):
    images = [
        'https://sun6-21.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/x03O_TwG67H6x-SLpuuGGrJ0sxjp1ApESmfZwR2gB5knVR07ObKOBI-VIWKCg2iPnVUkLIJQ.jpg?size=1280x1376&quality=96&crop=0,0,1280,1376&ava=1',
        'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ed/5b/35/ed5b35d92ed51daa77999327c99cb215.png',
        'https://kot-pes.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/post_5da84ea695ff8.jpeg',
        'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a8/71/cd/a871cd2eba7e45f2b517e3838e605049.jpg',
    ]
    random_image_url = random.choice(images)
    await ctx.send(random_image_url)

@bot.command()
async def kill(ctx, player_nickname):
    print(f"Killing player: {player_nickname}")
    image_urls = [
        "https://media.tenor.com/pTWL9X8k7O0AAAAd/senator-armstrong-raiden.gif",
        "http://www.abload.de/img/1361741288551lvcz9.gif",
        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fc/1f/13/fc1f13c418b93b087e60c6f6c664d7b9.gif",
    ]
    random_image_url = random.choice(image_urls)
    await ctx.send(random_image_url)

@bot.event
async def main():
    image_url = await kill(Nickname)
    print(image_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 
 @bot.command()
 async def dance(ctx, player_nickname):
    print(f"Dancing player: {player_nickname}")
    image_urls = [
        "https://media.tenor.com/MQfaMQjZN2cAAAAC/devil-may-cry5-dante.gif",
        "https://media.tenor.com/j7fKV15TbR0AAAAC/devil-may-cry-dante.gif",
        "https://media.tenor.com/gcODRgJtndIAAAAd/dmc3-jester.gif",
        "https://media1.tenor.com/images/efe7b891fc8cc6ac8f5a74fcdd50bee8/tenor.gif?itemid=17020042",
    ]     
    random_image_url = random.choice(image_urls)
    await ctx.send(random_image_url)

@bot.event
async def main():
    image_url = await dance(Nickname)
    print(image_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def graybutton(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction  ):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="This is an edited button response!")


@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "This message has buttons!",
        view=Buttons()
    ) 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   bot.run('')
```

А выдает такую ошибку:

> *discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view  for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.secondary: 2> url=None disabled=False label='Button' emoji=None row=None>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\viktor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
> await item.callback(interaction)
> File "c:/Users/viktor/Desktop/SSS/mport discord.ini", line 76, in graybutton
> await interaction.response.edit_message(content="This is an edited button response!")
> AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'*

Я искал как исправить эту ошибку, но не нашел. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: В заголовке должно быть краткое описание проблемы, а не твоя автобиография. [ask]